# When to choose zero-inflated Poisson models over traditional Poisson regression? When the proportion of zeros start being problematic?

Tags: regression, glm, poisson

I am learning generalised linear models on my own and while reading about regression models for count outcomes I found a recommendation to use zero-inflated Poisson or Negative Binomial regressions when facing an "excessive" or "considerable" amount of zero values in the outcome variable. However, I have been having a lot of difficulty trying to find a reference explicitly stating what proportion of zeros should be considered "excessive" to the point of warranting the use of zero-inflated models.